# GA4 Tracking of multidomain landing pages ecommerce not working

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, google-analytics-4

I'm stuck with an issue trying to track a multidomain website.

I have a main site **[www.example.com](http://www.example.com)**, and for ads I have created some subdomains for landing pages **landingA.example.com** and **landingB.example.com**

So finally the structure seems like this:

- [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) (Here the users can purchase products)
- landingA.example.com (Landing page that only contains a link to [www.example.com](http://www.example.com))
- landingB.example.com (Landing page that only contains a link to [www.example.com](http://www.example.com))

I'm trying to check at GA4 how many purchases I have thanks to my landing pages, but GA4, dont let me know that actually.

All purchases are assigned to [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) always.

[image]

I have checked through server side and I have some purchases thanks to that landing pages, but all is assigned to [www.example.com](http://www.example.com)

I want to create a report dash without the must of use the "explorer"

I have tried creating a custom event and tagging with an event, but didn't work

Custom event creation

[image]

Custom dimension

[image]

Thanks so much for your help!

At the moment I have tried the following:

1. Create a custom events at landing pages, but after I can't separate it automatically

For example at future may I have thousands of landing pages, and I can't set manually each of them.

2. Create a custom dimension from the event, and didn't work